# Can CVV be input in a standard web site? The site doesn't store it

Tags: pci-dss, e-commerce

On my website, payments are done using a PCI-compliant 3rd partner. If the client agrees, I store a TOKEN of the card (returned by the PCI partner).

I want to make a new payment **with CVV** for the stored token.

Can I display **on my website** the 4 last digits of the credit card and **a field** for the client to enter the CVV?
On submit, I send a payment request to the PCI partner with the token and the **entered** CVV. Of course I **don't** save the CVV.

Is this process offending PCI requirements?

If yes, does it mean I have to redirect my client to my PCI partner website in order to enter the CVV only in a PCI-compliant server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions: 3rd party partner is an approved Payment Processor, "Standard Website" means a site using HTTPS/TLS1.2, and all other PCI requirements are followed (e.g., data in transit encryption, server security, etc.).

Storing the token and sending it to the payment processor for reoccurring payments is a best practice.  This meets the requirements for PCI 3.5.1 - "PAN is rendered unreadable anywhere it is stored."

The payment processor may not require the CVV to be sent.  I'd make sure it's necessary before you go through the implementation.

**References**

[PCI Tokenization Product Security Guidelines](https://listings.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Tokenization_Product_Security_Guidelines.pdf)
[What is Tokenization and How Can I Use it for PCI DSS Compliance](https://www.securitymetrics.com/blog/what-tokenization-and-how-can-i-use-it-pci-dss-compliance)

Comment: Your assumptions are correct.
My Standard Website already works for payments that do NOT require CVV (the terminal /bank account used doesn't require CVV).
Newly I have the need to make payements REQUIRING CVV (the terminal /bank account requires CVV).

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer, it sounds like you align with PCI requirements, then.  I think your approach of showing the last four digits and requesting the CVV is sound.